# Update/refresh manually Blender's interface?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator

I need to manually refresh Blender's window/interface.

I'm working in my Addon's preferences, and I have an operator that modifies how things are drawed in a certain panel. I'd like to those changes to be noticeable when the user uses the operator inside the the preferences window, but right now, they only change when I manually move the mouse outside the preferences window (it triggers the draw()).

So, I was wondering if it was possible to manually call to update/redraw the interface.

Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `context.area.tag_redraw()` or `context.region.tag_redraw()`

Comment: Thank you so much friend! Adding some context in case is helpful for other users seeing the question, in my case calling those wasn't working since the area/region was the the 'PREFERENCES' panel/window (so I guess `context.area.tag_redraw()` was redrawing that preferences window).
So, to update Blender's interface, I had to:

        `screen:bpy.types.Screen`
        `for screen in bpy.data.screens:`
            `for area in screen.areas:`
                `area.tag_redraw()`

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: (Sorry for the bad multi-line code format, I don't know how to add it propperly)